# Problem with Pyserial read time

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial, rs485, python

I'm building a RS485 network with rpi3 as master and a bunch of c51 mcu as slaves. After sending an address, the master waits for the slave to respond and then starts to send data. I'm using Pyserial on Pi and it does a good job.

This is the class part

```
class Rs485(serial.Serial):
def __init__(self,en_pin):
    serial.Serial.__init__(self, '/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, write_timeout=3.0)
    self.en_pin = en_pin
    self.data_buf = 0
    self.parity =  serial.PARITY_SPACE
    self.init()
    self.timeout = 0.03
```

This is the part where read is called

```
def receive(self):
    ts.output(0, self.en_pin)
    data_buf = self.read()
    ts.output(1, self.en_pin)
    return data_buf
```

However, as I'm trying to enhance the transmission efficiency, I found that there is an unexpected delay after each time the serial.read is called. The ts.output lines are used to set max485 enable pin to receive mode and they cost almost no time. I have confirmed that the self.read line costs about 5.7ms.
[image]

My questions are:

1. Why the delay?
2. Any suggestions on how I could reduce the delay?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the protocol used? What is the mechanism to detect end of frame/message? Also, RPI normally uses not a real time OS, so it may have some delays before returning from function `self.read()`

Comment: @GAttuso, thanks. I'm using a protocol similar to modubus, but I don't think this would have an influence over the delay. As shown in the picture, the serial.read() itself already costs 5.7ms, which brings about 3.5ms delay. It could be the problem with the OS, but I noticed that the delay time is quite constant, always around 4.7ms. How can I determine if it is OS's problem? can I improve it? thanks again.

Comment: Modbus RTU uses 3.5 char silent interval to detect the end of frame ([check page 13](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf)). Thus if you use 9600 baudrate and 1 stop bit, this results in around 35/9600 = 3.65 ms delay minimum.